# plotting windrose in R

Tags: r, plot

Does anyone know what is the problem in my code below? I am trying to plot windrose in R. When I run this code nothing happens. Any idea?

```
# set the workspace first
setwd("c:/openair/documentation/primet")
# importing data to R
read.csv("c:/openair/documentation/primet/mydata2.csv")
# calling package "openair"
#library(openair)

openair:: windRose(mydata = mydata2)

#windRose(airwind,type = "default")
openair::windRose(mydata = mydata2,ws = "ws", wd = "wd", ws.int = 2,   angle =  30,type = "default")
# plot windrose 

plot.function(windRose(mydata = mydata2,ws = "ws", wd = "wd", ws.int =  2, angle = 30, type = "default"))
End
```

Comment: There are several problems (and probably some errors missing?). You don't assign the CSV you read to anything, so `mydata2` is never defined. So your `windRose` calls probably produce an error like `Error in <command>: object 'mydata2' not found`. And then your last line, `End`, isn't valid syntax so it also probably throws an error (unless you've defined an object and named it `End`).

Comment: thank you so much for your comment! I edited my code and ended up defining a function as windrose, but again the code does not run.